# How to print a text file using WiFi Direct

Tags: java, android, printing, wifi-direct

I have a working Android app that displays user stats. I want to send a small report with plain text format (.txt) to a WiFi  Direct printer. I have downloaded the sample [demo](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) app from Android. I did the proper modification in order to look for .txt file. But I don't understand why my code is not working. After selecting the file I want to print, nothing happens.

**The current configuration for my EPSON printer bellow.**

- Wi-Fi Direct Mode : On
- Communication Mode: AP
- Operation    Mode: IEEE802.11g/n
- Communication Speed: Auto
- SSID: DIRECT-D3A36C54
- Channel: 7
- Security Level: WPA2-PSK(AES)
- Link Status: Unknown

**This is the DeviceDetailFragment class**

```
public class DeviceDetailFragment extends Fragment implements WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener {
    protected static final int CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE = 20;
    private View mContentView = null;
    private WifiP2pDevice device;
    private WifiP2pInfo info;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_detail, null);
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
                config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
                config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.LABEL;
                config.wps.pin = "12345677";
//                config.groupOwnerIntent = 15;
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Press back to cancel",
                        "Connecting to :" + device.deviceAddress, true, true
//                        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
//
//                            @Override
//                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
//                                ((DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).cancelDisconnect();
//                            }
//                        }
                );
                ((DeviceListFragment.DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).connect(config);
            }
        });
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_disconnect).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((DeviceListFragment.DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).disconnect();
                    }
                });
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Allow user to pick a text file from storage or other
                        // registered apps
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.setType("text/*");
//                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE);
                    }
                });
        return mContentView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // User has picked a text file. Transfer it to group owner i.e peer using
        // FileTransferService.
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        TextView statusText = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        statusText.setText("Sending: " + uri);
        Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Intent----------- " + uri);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FileTransferService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(FileTransferService.ACTION_SEND_FILE);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_FILE_PATH, uri.toString());
        serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS,
                info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
        serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT, 8315); //631
        getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        this.info = info;
        this.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // The owner IP is now known.
        TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.group_owner);
        view.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.group_owner_text)
                + ((info.isGroupOwner == true) ? getResources().getString(R.string.yes)
                : getResources().getString(R.string.no)));
        // InetAddress from WifiP2pInfo struct.
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
        view.setText("Group Owner IP - " + info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
        // After the group negotiation, we assign the group owner as the file
        // server. The file server is single threaded, single connection server
        // socket.
        if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
            new FileServerAsyncTask(getActivity(), mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text))
                    .execute();
        } else if (info.groupFormed) {
            // The other device acts as the client. In this case, we enable the
            // get file button.
            mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text)).setText(getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.client_text));
        }
        // hide the connect button
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    /**
     * Updates the UI with device data
     *
     * @param device the device to be displayed
     */
    public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {
        this.device = device;
        this.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
        view.setText(device.deviceAddress);
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
        view.setText(device.toString());
    }
    /**
     * Clears the UI fields after a disconnect or direct mode disable operation.
     */
    public void resetViews() {
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
        view.setText(R.string.empty);
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
        view.setText(R.string.empty);
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.group_owner);
        view.setText(R.string.empty);
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        view.setText(R.string.empty);
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    /**
     * A simple server socket that accepts connection and writes some data on
     * the stream.
     */
    public static class FileServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private Context context;
        private TextView statusText;
        /**
         * @param context
         * @param statusText
         */
        public FileServerAsyncTask(Context context, View statusText) {
            this.context = context;
            this.statusText = (TextView) statusText;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8315); //631
                Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: Socket opened");
                Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

                Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: connection done");
//                final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
//                        + context.getPackageName() + "/wifip2pshared-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
//                        + ".txt");


                final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + context.getPackageName() + "/wifip2pshared-" + ".txt");
                File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
                if (!dirs.exists())
                    dirs.mkdirs();
                f.createNewFile();
                Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "server: copying files " + f.toString());
                InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
                copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));
                serverSocket.close();
                return f.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                statusText.setText("File copied - " + result);
//                Log.e("...File copied - ", result);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + result), "text/*");
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Log.e("File copied is NULL- ", result);
            }
        }
        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            statusText.setText("Opening a server socket");
        }
    }
    public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        try {
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT #1**
This is my permission setting

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_PRINT_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

After connecting to the printer, I've got the UI to select the file, after I select it, nothing happens, I just got the below console output (the file I am picking up is located in the SD card)

> - 05-17 10:39:50.994 28659-28659/com.example.ccano.wifidirect       E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
> - 05-17    10:39:52.314 28659-28659/com.example.ccano.wifidirect    D/ViewRootImpl:    ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
> - 05-17 10:39:52.384    28659-28659/com.example.ccano.wifidirect    D/ViewRootImpl:    ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
> - 05-17 10:39:56.484    28659-28659/com.example.ccano.wifidirect    D/wifidirectdemo:    Intent-----------
>     content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/9C33-6BBD%3Asample_file.txt
> - 05-17 10:39:56.514 28659-28659/com.example.ccano.wifidirect       D/wifidirectdemo: P2P state changed - 2
> - 05-17 10:39:56.514    28659-29309/com.example.ccano.wifidirect    D/wifidirectdemo: Opening    client socket -
> - 05-17 10:39:56.514    28659-28659/com.example.ccano.wifidirect    D/wifidirectdemo: Peer    status :0
> - 05-17 10:39:56.524 28659-29309/com.example.ccano.wifidirect       D/wifidirectdemo: Client socket - true
> - 05-17 10:39:56.524    28659-29309/com.example.ccano.wifidirect    E/ccano..copyfile: true
> - 05-17 10:39:56.524 28659-29309/com.example.ccano.wifidirect       D/wifidirectdemo: Client: Data written
> - 05-17 10:39:56.534    28659-28659/com.example.ccano.wifidirect    I/Timeline: Timeline:    Activity_idle id:
>     android.os.BinderProxy@75dd5e time:4602644
> - 05-17    10:41:01.714 28659-28659/com.example.ccano.wifidirect    D/ViewRootImpl:    ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
> - 05-17 10:41:01.774    28659-28659/com.example.ccano.wifidirect    D/ViewRootImpl:    ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
> - 05-17 10:41:02.564    28659-28659/com.example.ccano.wifidirect    D/wifidirectdemo: P2P peers    changed
> - 05-17 10:41:02.574 28659-28659/com.example.ccano.wifidirect       D/wifidirectdemo: Peer status :3
> - 05-17 10:41:02.594    28659-28659/com.example.ccano.wifidirect    D/wifidirectdemo: No devices    found

**EDIT #2**

After adding the below line into my manifiest, still I am getting same result, nothing happens.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

[image]

**Edit #3**

After changing WpsInfo.Label to WpsInfo.PBC now, I am getting a different output on the debugger console. (see screen shot below). But, still I the printer is not sending the print job.

[image]

Comment: `Android` OS version?

Comment: Can you provide more details about "nothing happens", is the WiFi Direct connection established? At which point does it fail from the output log?

Comment: The project is using Android 6.0 API level 23. The log show that the file was sent and the proper handshake was established.

Comment: did you add required permissions for the storage : 
'''<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
'''

Comment: Those permissions where set at the very beginning, since I cloned the Android demo described above in my description.see my re-edit post.

Comment: i still cant see READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Please check my Edit#2, still same issue.

Comment: are you sure your printer supports printing a txt file just by dumping it? I believe you may need to use ipp printing protocol to communicate with the printer.

Comment: set targetSdkVersion 22 (or you need to implement run time permissions)

Comment: @Carlos, please follow my edit post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that my code was fine, after several days of testing and doing research, I found out that the issue was the socket class, I was using the default one that Google provides in the demo code (which is the one I was using) but, after reading the official documentation from [Wi-Fi.org](http://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-direct) I could understand that port number matters and, in order to make it work with WiFi Direct only you have to target port #631 and the printer will ask you about the PIN password in case that it is enabled. Now, if you want to use P2P and by-passing the password, you have to use the port #9100.

So, I did it using both ports 9100 and 631 and now I am printing txt files.

Now, if you want to print PDF, you just need to add:

```
intent.setType("application/pdf");
```

and

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + result), "application/pdf");
```

to the DeviceDetailFragment class (the one is posted above).

I hope this post will provide a good understanding and inside about Android printing with P2P communication.